# PIL: How to write text images and automatically wrap?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The size of the Image is fixed.The length of the text is variable,and the text contains English and Chinese.how to write text images and automatically wrap?
My code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import os

text='测试测试测试测试测试testtesttesttesttest.....[[[[]]]]测试测试xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx试测试测试试测试测试试测试测试'
im = Image.open('xxx.png')
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join("fonts", "MSYH.TTC"), 30)
dr.text((10, 10), text , font=font, fill="#CB9410")
im.show()
```

Comment: There's nothing built-in I can think of, so you're likely going to need to write something to wrap the text yourself. Note: It's probably not that difficult and, as @J. Owens suggested in their "answer", using the `ImageDraw.textsize()` function will help you determine width of characters (or whole words if you want to word wrap).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the [`PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize) function to determine how long a given string is. You could then write something to adjust the string to fit and break it into multiple lines. I see there is also a [`PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.multiline_text`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.multiline_text) function that might help too.